# remove one unicode range from a unicode textfile in Python3

Tags: unicode, python-3.x

I have a Unicode textfile consisting of ranges q to r and s to t. I want to remove range s to t (which is in Chinese) leaving q to r (which is in English).

How can I do that in Python3?

Comment: What is a "range" in this case? "Ranges q to r" doesn't really mean anything, as q isn't a range, it's a letter. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the string translate method.  To quote from the 3.1.3 Std Lib doc:

```
str.translate(map) 
Return a copy of the s where all characters have been mapped through the map 
which must be a dictionary of Unicode ordinals (integers) to Unicode ordinals, 
strings or None. Unmapped characters are left untouched. Characters mapped to 
None are deleted.

You can use str.maketrans() to create a translation map from 
character-to-character mappings in different formats.
```